# Wordpress unrecognized expression: #the-comment-list [class^=delete:the-comment-list]

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have this error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #the-comment-list [class^=delete:the-comment-list]
```

on my Wordpress website http://www.michelepierri.it

This error does not allow jquery to work in the administrative panel.

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like a DOM selector to me. Please post the relevant JS where it is used.

Comment: Chrome developer tools link this file:
http://www.michelepierri.it/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery,hoverIntent,utils,common,json2,thickbox,underscore,shortcode,media-upload&ver=3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Solved, trash manager plugin do a conflict. I have disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [selectors documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) the `:` character is a special character in jQuery selectors, and as a result needs to be escaped so it's treated as just a regular `:` character when it appears in an id, class name, etc. There are two ways to do that. The most generic is to use two backslashes (`\`):

```
$('#the-comment-list [class^=delete\\:the-comment-list]')
```

However, since this is an attribute value, you can also get the same result by wrapping it in quotes:

```
$('#the-comment-list [class^="delete:the-comment-list"]')
```

Comment: @michele You'll need to modify the code calling that selector so that it escapes the `:` using either of the two methods suggested. I'm not familiar with Wordpress, but I assume you will be able to modify the code?

Comment: yes, but this is strange because I have never modified scripts...I don't understand where is the line to modify.